# Git merge divergent branches sequentially

Tags: git

My local branch `someNewFeature` has mistakenly diverged.

Running git status, shows this:

```
$ git status                     
On branch someNewFeature
Your branch and 'origin/someNewFeature' have diverged,
and have 8 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The git commit tree for the local branch looks like this:

```
* jjjjjjj commit 10
* iiiiiii commit 9
* hhhhhhh commit 8
* ggggggg commit 7
* fffffff commit 6
* eeeeeee commit 5
* ddddddd commit 4
* ccccccc commit 3
| * bbbbbbb Diverged commit
|/  
* aaaaaaa Base commit
```

I want to address the divergence by applying all the commits sequentially, i.e. it should look like this:

```
* jjjjjjj commit 10
* iiiiiii commit 9
* hhhhhhh commit 8
* ggggggg commit 7
* fffffff commit 6
* eeeeeee commit 5
* ddddddd commit 4
* ccccccc commit 3
* bbbbbbb Diverged commit 
* aaaaaaa Base commit
```

**Bonus:** If you could guess how I might have done this, I'd appreciate the insight.

Comment: Are you sure the commit referenced by `bbbbbbb` comes in a chronological ordering  before all other commits?

Comment: Yes, I am. I did the work earlier this evening.

Comment: Is `cccc` a merge commit which resulted from a `git pull origin/someNewFeature` after you made some changes (commits `dddd..jjjj`) to your local `someNewFeature` branch?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a simple `git rebase someNewFeature origin/someNewFeature`

Comment: Why the downvote? This would seem to achieve what they described they wanted, to put all the commits on top of origin/someNewFeature per "I want to address the divergence by applying all the commits sequentially, i.e. it should look like this:"

Comment: I do not get it either. To me it is a basic question and basic answer. I was also planing to answer using rebase :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid to mess up your repository and not sure about your git commands, I suggest [GitUp](http://gitup.co/) to work on git repositories. It has all merging / rebasing capabilities through visualization. It also has undo/redo function so if you mess up something you can always revert back. You can even re-order your commits.

Also here is a CLI answer: As far as I understand, you have a local branch named someNewFeature and you are working on that almost 8 commit. But on remote branch some other developer pushes some changes. And you want to get them and re-apply your changes on top of that. In order to do that you can run this command when you are in your `someNewFeature` branch:

```
git pull --rebase origin someNewFeature
```